# Trying to layout a table in html

Tags: html, html-table

I'm  trying to layout a table containing four columns: column 1 cell is six rows deep; column 2 cell is six rows deep; column 3 contains a cell four rows deep, and 2 cells one row deep; column 4 contains a cell three rows deep and a cell one row deep, with the last two cells in the column empty and unspecified.

```
ABCD
ABCD
ABCD
ABCE
ABFx
ABGx
```

I tried to follow what I think is the rule for doing this, namely: the first <tr> contains <td>s for everything in the first row; the second <tr> contains the <td>(s) to fill in columns for the first non-specified column(s) [in this case the cell called "E"], and the next two <tr>s contain a <td> each for "F" and "G".

The following code is my attempt:

```
    <table border='1'>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan='6'>A<br/>A<br/>A<br/>A<br/>A<br>A</td>
            <td rowspan='6'>B<br/>B<br/>B<br/>B<br/>B<br>B</td>
            <td rowspan='4'>C<br/>C<br/>C<br/>C</td>
            <td rowspan='3'>D<br/>D<br/>D</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>E</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>F</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>G</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

This gives me:

```
ABCDx
ABCDx
ABCDE
ABCDF
ABCGx
```

If I "guide it" with an unwanted column:

```
1ABCD
2ABCD
3ABCD
4ABCE
5ABF
6ABG
```

using:

```
    <table border='1'>
        <tr>
            <th>1</th>
            <td rowspan='6'>A<br/>A<br/>A<br/>A<br/>A<br>A</td>
            <td rowspan='6'>B<br/>B<br/>B<br/>B<br/>B<br>B</td>
            <td rowspan='4'>C<br/>C<br/>C<br/>C</td>
            <td rowspan='3'>D<br/>D<br/>D</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>2</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>3</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>4</th>
            <td>E</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>5</th>
            <td>F</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>6</th>
            <td>G</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

it comes out as expected.  So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Thank you for your astute observation. You are uncorrect in that I do understand that "rowspan" is used to extent a cell into succeeding rows.   That shoud have been evident in the use I made of it.

Comment: @JamieBarker
Thank you for your astute observation. You are incorrect in that I do understand that "rowspan" is used to extend a cell into succeeding rows. 

I did check in <cite>HTML5 and CSS All-in-One for Dummies</cite>, <cite>HTML, CSS, and Javascript Web Publishing</cite>,<cite>HTML &amp; CSS design and build websites</cite>, <cite>Beginning HTML with CSS and XHTML Modern Guide and Reference</cite>, and <cite>Mastering HTML</cite>, as well as numerous web searches before bothering you at stackoverflow. None showed &lt;tr> &lt;/tr> as the fix.

Comment: My point was you had a rowspan for 6 when you had maximum of 4 rows, which I figured would be glaringly obvious if you understood rowspan/colspan. Apparently not, my bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add two empty rows before row containing `E`

```
  <table border='1'>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan='6'>A<br/>A<br/>A<br/>A<br/>A<br>A</td>
        <td rowspan='6'>B<br/>B<br/>B<br/>B<br/>B<br>B</td>
        <td rowspan='4'>C<br/>C<br/>C<br/>C</td>
        <td rowspan='3'>D<br/>D<br/>D</td>
    </tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr>
        <td>E</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>F</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>G</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, to activate 6 rowspan, you need 6 not empty rows, like that http://codepen.io/Toomean/pen/dMeaqd

```
<table border='1'>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan='6'>A<br/>A<br/>A<br/>A<br/>A<br>A</td>
    <td rowspan='6'>B<br/>B<br/>B<br/>B<br/>B<br>B</td>
    <td rowspan='4'>C<br/>C<br/>C<br/>C</td>
    <td rowspan='3'>D<br/>D<br/>D</td>
  </tr>
  <tr></tr>
  <tr></tr>
  <tr>
    <td>E</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>F</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>G</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```